# Proper way to create a Symfony2 helper class which is available to all bundles

Tags: symfony

I'm implementing an ACL system for my models and I want to extract the common code into a common Helper class.  I can't find any examples of how to properly do something like this, but I constantly find the need to do it.

For example, let's say that in my controller I have a chunk of code (taken right from the docs):

```
      // creating the ACL
      $aclProvider = $this->get('security.acl.provider');
      $objectIdentity = ObjectIdentity::fromDomainObject($asset);
      $acl = $aclProvider->createAcl($objectIdentity);

      // retrieving the security identity of the currently logged-in user
      $securityContext = $this->get('security.context');
      $user = $securityContext->getToken()->getUser();
      $securityIdentity = UserSecurityIdentity::fromAccount($user);

      // grant owner access
      $acl->insertObjectAce($securityIdentity, MaskBuilder::MASK_OWNER);
      $aclProvider->updateAcl($acl);
```

I would much rather have the following:

```
      $this->get('my_helpers')->bindUserToObject($asset, MaskBuilder::MASK_OWNER);
```

How should I go about implementing the 'my_helpers' service?  I'm pretty sure it would be a service, but I still find the concept of 'services' to be a little confusing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok, for some reason the process of defining my question here helped me solve how to do this.  I did create a service.

```
class AclHelper {

protected $aclProvider;
protected $securityContext;
protected $logger;

    public function __construct(MutableAclProvider $aclProvider, $securityContext, $logger) {
      $this->aclProvider = $aclProvider;
      $this->securityContext = $securityContext;
      $this->logger = $logger;
    }   

    public function bindUserToObject($object, $mask) {
      // creating the ACL
      $objectIdentity = ObjectIdentity::fromDomainObject($object);
      $acl = $aclProvider->createAcl($objectIdentity);

      // retrieving the security identity of the currently logged-in user
      $user = $this->securityContext->getToken()->getUser();
      $securityIdentity = UserSecurityIdentity::fromAccount($user);

      // grant owner access
      $acl->insertObjectAce($securityIdentity, $mask);
      $aclProvider->updateAcl($acl); 
    }
}
```

Then I added it to my services.yml file:

```
parameters:
    acl_helper.class: GC\DashboardBundle\Services\AclHelper

services:
  acl_helper:
    class:  %acl_helper.class%
    arguments: [@security.acl.provider, @security.context, @logger]
```

Now in my controller, all I have to do is:

```
$this->get('acl_helper')->bindUserToObject($object, MaskBuilder::MASK_OWNER);
```

Comment: I think you should accept your answer since you found a solution for your question.

Answer (score 1):

There is a [bundle](https://github.com/Problematic/ProblematicAclManagerBundle) for that :).

Answer (score 0):

You're right, you have to create a service.
You can find more information about services and service container in [the official documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html).