# Moving replicated codes somewhere appropriate and access them from all controllers

Tags: symfony

I want to be able to access a code from all my controllers so what is the best way of doing it? The code below is to handle form errors and I've been replicating it in every single controller in my project.

So I want to keep `getErrorMessages()` somewhere else and access it in controller below.

**Note:** I read about [services](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html) but got confused and [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10866575/proper-way-to-create-a-symfony2-helper-class-which-is-available-to-all-bundles)!

**Example Controller:**

```
class HelloController extends Controller
{
    public function processAction(Request $request)
    {
        //More code here

        if ($form->isValid() !== true)
        {
            $errors = $this->getErrorMessages($form);

            return $this->render('SayHelloBundle:hello.html.twig',
                    array(
                        'page' => 'Say Hello',
                        'form' => $form->createView(),
                        'form_errors' => $errors
                    ));
        }

        //More code here
    }

    private function getErrorMessages(FormInterface $form)
    {
        $errors = array();

        foreach ($form->getErrors() as $error)
        {
            $errors[] = $error->getMessage();
        }

        foreach ($form->all() as $child)
        {
            if (! $child->isValid())
            {
                $options = $child->getConfig()->getOptions();
                $field = $options['label'] ? $options['label'] : $child->getName();
                $errors[$field] = implode('; ', $this->getErrorMessages($child));
            }
        }

        return $errors;
    }
}
```

Comment: if you use the Form Symfony2 Component you don't need the getErrorMessages function because errors are automatically handled by the form component (see docs about Forms in the Book, Cookbook and Components).

Comment: Code above is just an example!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK did it :)

**/var/www/html/local/sport/app/config/config.yml**

```
imports:
    - { resource: services.yml }
```

**/var/www/html/local/sport/app/config/services.yml**

```
parameters:
    form_errors.class: Football\TeamBundle\Services\FormErrors

services:
    form_errors:
        class:  %form_errors.class%
```

**/var/www/html/local/sport/src/Football/TeamBundle/Services/FormErrors.php**

```
namespace Football\TeamBundle\Services;

use Symfony\Component\Form\FormInterface;


class FormErrors
{
    public function getErrors(FormInterface $form)
    {
        $errors = array();

        //This part get global form errors (like csrf token error)
        foreach ($form->getErrors() as $error)
        {
            $errors[] = $error->getMessage();
        }

        //This part get errors for form fields
        foreach ($form->all() as $child)
        {
            if (! $child->isValid())
            {
                $options = $child->getConfig()->getOptions();
                $field = $options['label'] ? $options['label'] : ucwords($child->getName());
                //There can be more than one field error, that's why implode is here
                $errors[strtolower($field)] = implode('; ', $this->getErrors($child));
            }
        }

        return $errors;
    }
}
```

**controller**

```
if ($form->isValid() !== true) {
    $errors = $this->get('form_errors')->getErrors($form);
    echo '<pre>'; print_r($errors); exit;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a class that has all the base operations in it and call that class (or set of classes) in your controllers.